# Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect in android studio

Tags: android

I use android studio and I want to use the **Generate signed APK** for releasing the **apk** file. but in continue, I see the following message:

> Keytool error:java.io.IOException:Keystore was tampered  with, or
>   password is incorrect

Also, my password is correct.Location of **Keystore** is at the following address:

```
C:\User\tec\.android\debug Keystore
```

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: I use from this [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html). But in that site is used **Keystore.release.jks** But I have **debug.Keystore** without the **jks** format in **.android** folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works in Android Studio, but in Unity you have do create a file called somename.keystore. After that you have to enter your password and username (you have entered when you created your .keystore)

this viedeo should work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0GUc9mABLY